# Where is the error? - TikZ (angles)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc, angle

In my thesis I'm doing a drawing with `TikZ`, but I get an error that I do not understand. Consider this code (simplified from the original, but still quite significant):

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
% definitions and macros
\def\pSpess{.5}
\def\pL{2.5}
\def\pAng{55}
\def\pRaggio{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pRaggioMin}{\pRaggio-\pSpess}

% coordinates

% above
\draw (-5,.7) arc (235:270:\pRaggio cm) -- ++(\pL,0) -- ++(0,\pSpess) -- ++(-\pL,0) arc (270:180+\pAng:\pRaggioMin cm) -- (-5,.7) node (a) [pos=.5] {} -- cycle;
    \coordinate (cmu) at ($(a)+(90+\pAng:.15)$); %centro momento
    \coordinate (imu) at ($(cmu)+(180+\pAng:.5)$); %inizio momento
    \coordinate (ccmu) at ($(cmu)+(90+\pAng:.25)$); %punto intermedio momento
    \coordinate (fmu) at ($(cmu)+(\pAng:.5)$); %fine momento
\draw [->] (imu) .. (ccmu) .. (fmu);

% bottom
\draw (-5,-.7) arc (125:90:\pRaggio cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

As you can see the design is not correct (there is a clear intersection that should not be there). However I do not understand what's wrong. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the example can be minimised to `\begin{tikzpicture} \draw (-5,.7) arc (235:270:4cm);
\draw (-5,-.7) arc (125:90:4cm); \end{tikzpicture}`, right?

Comment: @Marco87 My pleasure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is due to the y-coordinates you use for the starting points of your arcs: They shouldn't be `0.7` and `-0.7`, but `0.723391823` and `-0.723391823` (which is `1-cos(35 degrees))*4cm`).

---

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
% definitions and macros
\def\pSpess{.5}
\def\pL{2.5}
\def\pAng{55}
\def\pRaggio{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pRaggioMin}{\pRaggio-\pSpess}

% coordinates

% above
\draw (-5,{1-cos(35))*\pRaggio cm}) arc (235:270:\pRaggio cm) -- ++(\pL,0) -- ++(0,\pSpess) -- ++(-\pL,0) arc (270:180+\pAng:\pRaggioMin cm) -- (-5,.7) node (a) [pos=.5] {} -- cycle;
    \coordinate (cmu) at ($(a)+(90+\pAng:.15)$); %centro momento
    \coordinate (imu) at ($(cmu)+(180+\pAng:.5)$); %inizio momento
    \coordinate (ccmu) at ($(cmu)+(90+\pAng:.25)$); %punto intermedio momento
    \coordinate (fmu) at ($(cmu)+(\pAng:.5)$); %fine momento
\draw [->] (imu) .. (ccmu) .. (fmu);

% bottom
\draw (-5,{1-cos(35))*-\pRaggio cm}) arc (125:90:\pRaggio cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]